# including html template, ng-include doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, html-templates

I'm working on a personal project using angularJS. I downloaded this html template online and when i tested the template it is working perfectly. The problem is that when i try to include a page from the template to my project using the ng-include, nothing happens, no error but also nothing displayed just a blank page. 
Basically my project is structured as following :

- src > app > template > index.html (this is the location of the template's main page).
- src > app > components > home > home.component.html (home page of my project)

Basically i want to include index.html in home.component.html, but ng-include is not working :/

Here is my code in home.component.html :

```
<div ng-app = "" ng-controller = "homeController">
  <div ng-include = "'/app/template/index.html'"> </div>
</div>
```

thank you very much :)

Comment: Are you getting an error on the network tab of the console tools? I would expect it is trying to find your file, but not finding it at the `ng-include` location. It looks like your include is looking in `app/trueshoes` but in your question you say the `index.html` is in `app/template`.

Comment: ohh i'm sorry i just realised, it's just a typo, it is /app/template/index.html, i corrected it in my question

Comment: i'm not having any error on the console

Comment: Are you including the angular source files in your html and are they loading correctly? Can you do a `console.log()` from within your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put just the way of template, like this:

```
<div ng-app = "" ng-controller = "homeController">
    <div ng-include = "'/template/index.html'"> </div>
</div>
```